# Silverlight specific Image shifting to the right

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am generating a set images to form a human body so that I can use for a physics engine.
The images generated are in a specific user control in where I set the dimentions and co-ordinates of each image. That usercontrol is then loaded in another user control but for some reason when the images are loaded, one specific image which I named (rightBicep) is shifting to the right. Here is a screenshot :

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/592/imageshift.jpg](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/592/imageshift.jpg)

I illustrated the positions of the images with dotted lines, the green dotted line is refering to where the image should be located, and the red dotted line is where the image is being shown.

The weird thing is the image beneath it (called rightForearm) take's it's LeftPosition from it, and when during debugging they have the exact same leftProperty value. Here's the syntax :

```
        public void generateRightBicep(string imageUrl)
        {
            rightBicep = new Image();            
            rightBicep.Name = CharacterName + "rightbicep";
            Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Relative);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rightBicep);

            rightBicep.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
            rightBicep.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(bodyPart_ImageOpened);

        }

       public void rightBicepLoaded()
        {
            var bi = waitTillImageLoad(rightBicep.Name);
            rightBicep.Height = elbowToArmpit + (2 * palm);
            rightBicep.Width = ratio(bi.PixelHeight, bi.PixelHeight, rightBicep.Height); // to be determined

            Vector2 topVector;
            topVector.X = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(torso.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) - palm);
            topVector.Y = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(neck.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + neck.Height);

            if (!faceRight)
            {
                perspectiveVectorHeight(ref topVector, ref rightBicep, torso.Width);
                rightBicep.Width = ratio(bi.PixelHeight, bi.PixelHeight, rightBicep.Height);
            }

            rightBicep.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(topVector.X));
            rightBicep.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(topVector.Y));
            rightBicep.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, rightBicepZindex);
            generateRightShoulder();
        }


public void generateRightForearm(string imageUrl)
        {
            rightForearm = new Image();
            rightForearm.Name = CharacterName + "rightforearm";
            Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Relative);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rightForearm);
            rightForearm.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
            rightForearm.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(bodyPart_ImageOpened);

        }

 public void rightForearmLoaded()
        {
            var bi = waitTillImageLoad(rightForearm.Name);
            rightForearm.Height = (elbowToHandTip - handLength) + palm;
            rightForearm.Width = ratio(bi.PixelHeight, bi.PixelWidth, rightForearm.Height);

            Vector2 topVector;
            if (faceRight)
            {
                topVector.X = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(rightBicep.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)));
                topVector.Y = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(rightBicep.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + rightBicep.Height - palm);
            }
            else
            {
                topVector.X = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(leftBicep.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)));
                topVector.Y = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(leftBicep.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + leftBicep.Height - palm);

                perspectiveVectorHeight(ref topVector, ref rightForearm, torso.Width);
                rightForearm.Width = ratio(bi.PixelHeight, bi.PixelWidth, rightForearm.Height);
            }

            rightForearm.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(topVector.X));
            rightForearm.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(topVector.Y));
            rightForearm.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, rightForearmZIndex);
            generateRightElbow();
        }
```

Now all the values I am adding together are a group of doubles I preset, and the property faceRight is to dertmine if the human body is facing right or left to determine where the positions of the body parts (since if the right hand looks on the left hand side when the human body turns the other way).

If you notice the rightforearm is taking the leftproperty of the rightbicep, so technically it should display direcrly underneath which it isn't. I also debugged the user control and both have the left property of -3.

PS. I call the methods `rightbicepLoaded` and `rightforearmLoaded` when an event is called when all the imageOpened events all have been triggered.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found out why , in my method ratio it should take hieght and width, and I put and i put 2 hieghts instead